# Log file batch script with expire date

Tags: date, batch-file, logging

I have a small problem with a log file. It must save in log a current date and a expire date which is 10 days. Something like this:

```
date: 27.08.2014 expire date: 06.09.2014.
```

I have tried script:

```
PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but I cant figure out, how to insert it in a log.txt file.

Have tried `>>C:\log.txt`

Please help!

Comment: if you get an `access denied` error when using `PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')  >>c:\log.txt` then use a different folder to save the file into.

Comment: No access denied message. I get in log file only ECHO off message. No data about date.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't use the `echo` command.  Show us the actual code that you are using.

Comment: echo DATE: %DATE% >>C:\log.txt
echo EXPIRE DATE: %"PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(+10); $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"% >>C:\log.txt
exit

Comment: The code you have in your question works fine.  The code you have in the comment above won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way: it just adds the part at the end of the line.

```
PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') >>"c:\log.txt"
```